# Trying to grasp JQuery. Working on chaining image fade ins but keep fading simultaneously

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Working with some JQuery, which I have little experience with, and trying to use

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
```

to chain the fade ins of 4 different images. However, they keep fading in at the same time. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function($){
    //$('.container.front-end h1').html($('.container.front-end h1').html().
    replace('&amp;', '<div class="h1-specialchar">&amp;</div>'));

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fade1').removeClass('transparent').addClass('fadeInDown');
    },1000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fade2').removeClass('transparent').addClass('fadeInDown');
    },2000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fade3').removeClass('transparent').addClass('fadeInDown');
    },3000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('#fade4').removeClass('transparent').addClass('fadeInRight');
    },4000);
  });

.row
  .span5{:style => "width: 400px;"}
    .pad-bottom70
    =image_tag(@page.photos[1].image_url(:full), :id => "fade1", :class => "animated fadeInDown") if @page.photos[1].image?
    .pad-bottom10
    =image_tag(@page.photos[2].image_url(:full), :id => "fade2", :class => "animated fadeInDown") if @page.photos[2].image?
    .pad-bottom5
    =image_tag(@page.photos[3].image_url(:full), :id => "fade3", :class => "animated fadeInDown") if @page.photos[3].image?
  .span7
    - unless @page.photos.empty?
      .pad-bottom70
      =image_tag(@page.photos[0].image_url(:full), :id => "fade4", :class => "animated fadeInRight") if @page.photos[0].image?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually use timeouts like that because they all will start at the same time.

You have to "chain" the actions together. Here's a jsfiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/vooboo13/Dp2SF/1/

In my example I'm using s because I don't have images, but here's how I did it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#box1").fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).queue(function(){                                 
        $("#box2").fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $("#box3").fadeIn('slow');
    })});

});
```

Comment: Hi Vu, thanks for getting back to me with your response. I have one question though...shouldn't using the set timeout function in the example above simulate a chain given that I've staggered the wait times after which the different functions should be executed??

Comment: You're right, I actually didn't notice you had set it for different wait times. Is everything working for you?

Comment: I actually ended up changing the whole thing around. Got something similar working on another page though. Still no idea what was going on there. Very strange. Thanks for the followup! What's the proper way to give "credit" in a situation like this? Does an upvote suffice, or?